# How to use HSQLDB to dynamically generate tables for JDBC application

Tags: java, jdbc, integration-testing, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I want to use HyperSQL as an in-memory database for integration tests of a Java - JDBC application.

If I try the following:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("user", "sa");
props.put("password", "");
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem://localhost", props);

Statement st = cn.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate("Insert into foo (bar) values (10);");
```

I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Table not found: foo in statement [Insert into bar]
```

I thought there was a way for HSQL to dynamically generate the tables when used as an in-memory database, but I can't seem to find it in the documentation.

Comment: do you already have `foo` in your database? how can it know schema of it if it doesn't exist already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you executing a query for an INSERT?  That won't return a `ResultSet`.

You ought to `executeUpdate()`

There's nothing "automatic" in HSQL.  You might be thinking of Hibernate and its hbm2ddl.

Comment: Oops, got slopping in experimenting. Edited.